# SVG animation not working in IE9/IE10 but works in Firefox and chrome

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

Please refer the below code.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="curtainClip">
            <rect id="clipRect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <animate xlink:href="#clipRect"
        attributeName="width" 
        dur="15s"
        from="0" 
        to="100" />

    <path clip-path="url(#curtainClip)" stroke="red" d="M 0 0 L 100 100"/>
</svg>
```

SVg animate element not working in  IE browser. how can i fix this ? whether it is bug in IE10 browser or i need to add any further code to work in IE browser.

i have referred the following link.

[Can't make SVG animation work with ie9 and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010056/cant-make-svg-animation-work-with-ie9-and-firefox)

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: do you get any javascript errors in the debug mode of IE ?

Comment: No javascript error in IE. svg component displayed but animation only not working in IE.

Answer (score 3):

You're using SMIL (declarative) animation, which is [not supported in Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/svg-smil). As far as I can tell, Microsoft has no plans to ever support it. From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg193979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#example1) page,

> "script-based animation opens the door to simple as well as complex
>   animation possibilities. Because of this, and for other reasons (such
>   as CSS animations), IE9 does not support declarative animation."

Microsoft really wants you to use script based animation. So if you want your SVG to animate in all current browsers, you'll need to do it with Javascript. Alternatively, as hinted at by Microsoft, you could use [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations). In my opinion, a CSS animation would be the best choice for the simple animation in your example.

Comment: It is possible to use FakeSMILe to make IE9+ animate declarative elements, see http://leunen.me/fakesmile/index.html.

Comment: As always with Microsoft: everybody else supports this standard, but we'll cock-block you from using it. Thankfully there are libraries that polyfill stuff, but guess what? The IE users are the ones who pay the price for poorer performance.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Ah, this does not work in background images. FWIW.